# Why are Async callback executed in WPF UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

Regarding this piece of code :

```
static async Task<string> testc()
{
    Console.WriteLine("helo async " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
    await Task.Run(() => { 
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("task " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); 
    });
    Console.WriteLine("callback "+Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return "bob";
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("helo sync " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    testc();
    Console.WriteLine("over" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I get the following output:

```
helo sync 10
helo async 10
over10
task 11
callback **11**
```

Which is OK : piece of code after await is executed in the same thread as task itself.

Now, if I do it in a WPF application :

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("helo sync " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    testc();
    Console.WriteLine("over" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It generates following output:

```
helo sync 8
helo async 8
over8
task 9
callback **8**
```

Where we can see code after await executed in the UI thread. Well, this is great since it enables manipulating observable collections etc... But I was wondering "Why?" "How could I do the same?" Is this related to some TaskScheduler behavior ? Is this hard-coded in the .NET Framework ?

Thx for any idea you may submit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that Task.Run will capture the [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) if one is present as it is in a WPF app when starting the task from the UI thread.  The Task will then use the `SynchronizationContext` to serialize the callback to the UI thread.  However, if no context is awailable as in a Console app, the callback will happen on a different thread.

Stephen Toub has described this in a [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).

BTW, <strike>be careful when using</strike> never use Thread.Sleep in a Task.  It may cause strange behaviour because a task may not be tied to one thread.  Use Task.Delay instead.

Answer (score 2):

> But I was wondering "Why?"

You've answered that yourself:

> Well, this is great since it enables manipulating observable collections etc...

The whole point of async is to make asynchrony easier to work with - so you can write "synchronous-looking" code which is actually asynchronous. That often includes wanting to stick within one context (e.g. a UI thread) for the whole of the async method - just "pausing" the method (without blocking the UI thread) when you need to await something.

> "How could I do the same?"

It's not clear what you mean here. Basically, the implementation of the awaitable pattern for `Task` uses [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx) to work out which scheduler to post the callback on - unless you've called [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait.aspx) to explicitly opt out of this behaviour. So that's how it manages it... whether or not you could "do the same" depends on exactly what you're trying to do.

See the "what are awaitables" question in the [async/await FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx) for more details of the awaitable pattern.

Comment: By "How could I do the same?" I think he means: "how do I get the WPF behaviour without using WPF?"

Comment: @jdv-JandeVaan: If that was the meaning, it's extremely unclear. Anyway, hopefully the details I've given will give enough information to take the OP further. They can always ask for more details if necessary.

Comment: Ok.. Fine. I don't really want to do the same. I was wondering how the callback is sent to Dispatcher.Invoke method... and if I could, eventually, do a similar thing or if it was hard coded in the Framework. Thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. The other answers are *almost* correct.

When you `await` a `Task` that has not yet completed, by default a "context" is captured which is used to resume the method when the `Task` completes. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` *unless it is null*, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Note the conditions required for this to work:

- "When you `await`..." - if you schedule a continuation manually, e.g., with `Task.ContinueWith`, no context capture is done. You have to do it yourself using something like `(SynchronizationContext.Current == null ? TaskSchedler.Current : TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())`.
- "...`await` a `Task`..." - this behavior is part of the `await` behavior *for `Task` types*. Other types may or may not do a similar capture.
- "...that has not yet completed..." - if the `Task` is already complete by the time it's `await`ed, the `async` method will continue *synchronously*. So there's no need to capture context in that case.
- "...by default..." - this is the default behavior and can be changed. In particular, call the `Task.ConfigureAwait` method and pass `false` for the `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter. This method returns an awaitable type (not a `Task`) that will not continue on the captured context if its parameter was `false`.

Comment: Thx for this complete answer. Most of it (or at least enough to answer my question) was in the link in @Jakob Christensen's answer, but I apreciate this full point of view!